# Gitlab Runner Removed Cache (files/container)

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

My "problem" is when i run my ci on my remote docker machine, the gitlab-runner leaves the container that has been used there without to remove them. The other thing is that the project sources are also given when you show into the volumes folder.

Does someone has maybe ideas how i can change it, that the container and project sources will be deleted after ci-pipeline run?

Good Regards,
cRUSH

```
stages:
- Build
- Testing
- Execute
- Publish
- CleanUp

build_cleanup:
    only:
        - master
    stage: Build
    script:
        - "dotnet clean"
        - (if  [ $(docker ps -a | grep $CONTAINER_NAME | cut -d " " -f1) ]; then echo $(docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME); else echo OK; fi;);
        - (if  [ $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true) ]; then echo $(docker volume prune -f); else echo OK; fi;);
    when: on_failure

testing_cleanup:
    only:
        - master
    stage: Testing
    script:
        - "dotnet clean"
        - (if  [ $(docker ps -a | grep $CONTAINER_NAME | cut -d " " -f1) ]; then echo $(docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME); else echo OK; fi;);
        - (if  [ $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true) ]; then echo $(docker volume prune -f); else echo OK; fi;);
    when: on_failure

excecute_cleanup:
    only:
        - master
    stage: Execute
    script:
        - "dotnet clean"
        - (if  [ $(docker ps -a | grep $CONTAINER_NAME | cut -d " " -f1) ]; then echo $(docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME); else echo OK; fi;);
        - (if  [ $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true) ]; then echo $(docker volume prune -f); else echo OK; fi;);
    when: on_failure

publish_cleanup:
    only:
        - master
    stage: Publish
    script:
        - "dotnet clean"
        - (if  [ $(docker ps -a | grep $CONTAINER_NAME | cut -d " " -f1) ]; then echo $(docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME); else echo OK; fi;);
        - (if  [ $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true) ]; then echo $(docker volume prune -f); else echo OK; fi;);
    when: on_failure

cleanup_jobs:
    only:
        - master
    stage: CleanUp
    script: 
        - "dotnet clean"
        - (if  [ $(docker ps -a | grep $CONTAINER_NAME | cut -d " " -f1) ]; then echo $(docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME); else echo OK; fi;);
        - (if  [ $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true) ]; then echo $(docker volume prune -f); else echo OK; fi;);
    when: always
```

This is my current configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is better to leave it there because it will leave the Docker building cache and next time the image is building it might be faster. However, in docker there is command `docker system df` that tells you how much space docker consume on your machine.

If you want to delete everything (**NOT CURRENTLY USED** docker images, volumes, containers...) just clean your machine with

```
docker system prune --volumes --all --force
```

The ideal place where to put this command with gitlab-ci is in [after_script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script)

```
job:
  script:
    - docker build .
  after_script:
    - docker system prune --volumes --all --force
```

Comment: I will check it :D

Comment: stages:
    - Build
    - Testing
    - Execute
    - Publish
    - CleanUp
build_cleanup:
    only:
        - master
    stage: Build
    script:
        - "dotnet clean"
        - (if  [ $(docker ps -a | grep $CONTAINER_NAME | cut -d " " -f1) ]; then echo $(docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME); else echo OK; fi;);
        - (if  [ $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true) ]; then echo $(docker volume prune -f); else echo OK; fi;);
    when: on_failure

Comment: This i have used until now but it dont removes the container. i will test your example

Comment: Your code dont works. My gitlab-ci is running inside docker. The output: docker system prune --volumes --all --force
/bin/bash: line 77: docker: command not found

Comment: update your question with your configuration and formatted, are you aware you can specify container name with `--name` so you dont have to search for $CONTAINER_NAME? if command `docker ps` works in your pipeline so must `docker system df`

Comment: Its working now because i deactivated the cache for the gitlab runner. This seems to be also faster then with caching enabled.

Comment: you could also check the [overlay2](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#using-the-overlayfs-driver) for faster builds

Comment: What would be the difference if i use overlay2? How does overlay2 make by build faster?